# useradd works interactively, but not in bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to automate the creation of user accounts.

The commands in this script work fine interactively in the bash shell, however when I run this bash script, it fails and I get a return of 2 which stands for `invalid command syntax` according to the useradd man page.

This script also prints out the command before it executes it, so if I simply copy/paste that output (without the `"cmd-->"`), it works.

E.g., `cmd-->useradd bidwbre -m -c "Brent Bidwel" -G students`
Here's the short script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read id fn ln pw
do
     echo "cmd-->useradd $id -m -c \"$fn $ln\" -G students"
     useradd $id -m -c \"$fn $ln\" -G students
     echo $?

    # chmod go-rx /home/$id
    # echo "$id:$pw" | chpasswd
    echo ""
done
```

I'm running this logged in as root, here are the permissions on the file.

`-rwxr-x---. 1 root root 1339 Aug  2 14:58 rh_make_accts.sh*`

What am I missing here?

Red Hat 7.3 Enterprise Linux

PS: Somewhat unrelated, but since I'm already asking: What is that trailing period in the long directory listing at the end of the permissions? Not something I've seen before - specific to RH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the two backslashes on the `useradd` line, or in other words, don't escape the quotes.

```
useradd $id -m -c "$fn $ln" -G students
```

PS: The dot

> [GNU Coreutils: What information is listed](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html)
>
> -l, --format=long, --format=verbose
>
> ...
>
> Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies
>   whether an alternate access method such as an access control list
>   applies to the file. When the character following the file mode bits
>   is a space, there is no alternate access method. When it is a printing
>   character, then there is such a method.
>
> GNU ls uses a ‘.’ character to indicate a file with a security
>   context, but no other alternate access method.
>
> A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
>   marked with a ‘+’ character.

Comment: Thank you .. just discovered that I don't need the backslashes on the quotes .. odd this script worked perfectly under Ubuntu (well, adduser vs useradd) for years, but i didn't expect the escaped quotes to be a problem. Thanks also for the `.` explanation. (Can't accept the answer for 5 more minutes ... )